# React Native Current Location merking

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, native, react-native-maps

I like to get current location marked when press button. I don't understand how <Mapview> rendered data because in <Text> lattitude and longitude value is showing but the marked is not showing in map.thats why i did a consol.warn in getGeolocation. So in the same time current locattion is showing inside text but console.warn said the value of lattitude and longtitude is zero. here is my code.

I am doing this project on react-native-android

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, Button } from "react-native";
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs";
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';


const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const Pageone = () => {

 

  useEffect(() => {
    requestLocationPermission();
  }, []);

  const requestLocationPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
          title: 'Location Permission',
          message: 'App needs access to your location.',
          buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          buttonPositive: 'OK',
        }
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        // You can now use Geolocation to get the current location
      } else {
        console.log('Location permission denied');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  };

  const [region, setRegion] = useState({
    latitude: 51.5079145,
    longitude: -0.0899163,
    latitudeDelta: 0.01,
    longitudeDelta: 0.01,
  });

  const markers = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Marker 1",
      description: "Description 1",
      coordinate: {
        latitude: 22.3410342,
        longitude: 91.83705599999999,
      },
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Marker 2",
      description: "Description 2",
      coordinate: {
        latitude: 22.34021255163955,
        longitude: 91.83541198713495,
      },
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Marker 3",
      description: "Description 3",
      coordinate: {
        latitude: 22.343437672482615,
        longitude: 91.83761139852795,
      },
    }
  ]
  const [Lag,setLag]=useState(0);
  const [Log,setLog]=useState(0);
  const getCurrentLocation = () => {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
        //console.warn('Current location:', latitude, longitude);
        setLag(position.coords.latitude);
        setLog(position.coords.longitude);
        console.warn(Lag);

      },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error.message);
      },
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
    );
  };
  
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <MapView
        style={{ height: 300, width: "100%" }}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 59.86766324483125, 
          longitude: -117.03713987115384,
          latitudeDelta: 0.01,
          longitudeDelta: 0.1,
        }}
        onRegionChangeComplete={(region) => setRegion(region)}
      >
        
           {<Marker
            coordinate={{latitude:Lag,longitude:Log}}
            title={"Current Location"}
            description={"User's current location"}
          /> 
        }
`your text`

      </MapView>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, marginTop: 20 }}>Current latitude: {region.latitude}</Text>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, paddingBottom: 20 }}>Current longitude: {region.longitude}</Text>

      <Button title="Get Current Location" onPress={getCurrentLocation} />

      <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, paddingTop: 20 }}>Current lag: {Lag}</Text>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, paddingTop: 20 }}>Current long: {Log}</Text>


    </View>
  );
}

const PageTwo = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>hello</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export const TopTab = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Pageone" component={Pageone} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Pagetwo" component={PageTwo} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```